# Rename Rails Params for AXLSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, axlsx

I am getting a dynamic array of fields from my front end application to determine what contents my workbook will have. Two of the fields will have the same value, but I want different column headings. So I have added this to my method:

```
    fields = params[:fields]
    fields[0].replace('new string')
    sheet.add_row fields
    exportees.each do |event_session_registration|
      row_array = params[:fields].map { |field| event_session_registration.try(field) }
      row_array.map! { |value| value == true ? 'Yes' : value }
      row_array.map! { |value| value == false ? 'No' : value }
      sheet.add_row row_array
    end
```

`Fields[0]` being the first of the two identical strings.

The problem now is that inside of my `.each` loop, `params[:fields]` now has the same contents as my updated `fields` variable. I have tried using `.dup` but that didn't leave my params unaltered either. I am able to get around this problem by doing the following:

```
    fields = params[:fields]
    fields[0].replace('new string')
    sheet.add_row fields
    fields[0].replace('original string')
```

However, I'm curious if there is a cleaner way to duplicate my params for the sake of printing different column headers. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
parameters = params.to_h
fields = parameters[:fields]
```

Comment: `params[:fields]` is just a simple array, which you can't call `.to_h` on. I'm not sure turning `fields` into a hash will slim this down.

Comment: params is an instances of _ActionController::Parameters_ that as all object has an object_id, if your assign _fields = params[:fields]_ this assignation is by reference, and the _object_id_ is still the same, so, when you convert params to a hash the object is completely different, so you can do something like  _parameters = params.to_h_ and _fields = parameters[:fields]_ I edited my suggestion above